# Install MySQL in docker volume, is possible? Linux

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-container

for educational reasons my professor wants me to try to install the mysql server inside a docker volume associated with a certain container. Do you think it is possible? I don't know how to do it, I searched on the internet but nothing can be found.

The "apt-get" commands inside the volume don't work even though I'm using a container with ubuntu: 18.04

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: It's possible to install mysql server inside a running docker container. Then you can configure its data directory to use a docker volume. Though usually all of this happens at build time in the Dockerfile.

Comment: could you please give me a practical example? I have a server (leshan) inside a container which stores data inside mysql (which for now is located in another container). My professor asked me to try to associate a volume in which mysql is inserted into the container of the leshan server. @aymericbeaumet

Comment: Where is the MySQL instance supposed to be located? What is the rationale behind collocating them in the same container?

Comment: Once you have run the container containing the leshan server you would like the mysql server to start up too so that the associated data on them. You want to do this because I was asked to see the memory expenditure of the two services in the same container rather than in two different containers. @aymericbeaumet